# getting error in struct definition in header file

Tags: c

I got a task from university to program an assembler of an imaginary compute, and an imaginary assembly language.

One of the files of the assembler is the 'firstpass.c' file, which has a header file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 82
#define MAX_LABEL_LENGTH 31
#define DELIMITERS " \t\n"

#define VAL_DC 0
#define VAL_IC 1

#define LAST_CHARACTER(string) *(string+strlen(string)-1)

enum opcodes {Mov = 0, Cmp, Add, Sub, Not, Clr, Lea, Inc, Dec, Jmp, Bne, Red, Prn, Jsr, Rts, Stop};
enum addressingModes {Immidiate = 1, Direct = 3, Register = 5};
enum errors {No_Valid_Operation = 0, Cant_Read_Line, Label_Already_Exists};

typedef struct label{
    char name[MAX_LABEL_LENGTH]; 
    int line; /*the line the table was defined*/ 
    int type;
    int counterType;
    label* next;
} label;

FILE* open_file(char* fileName, int numOfEntries, char* ending);
int add_label(label* labelHead, char labelName[], int counterType, int lineNum);
int error_handler(int errorCode, int lineNum);
int is_instruction_operator();
int is_guidance_operation(label* labelHead, char labelName[], char* token, int isLabel, int lineNum);
int is_label(char* token, char labelName[], char originalLine[]);
int input_handler();
```

I keep "getting unknown type name 'label'" error, and I can't figure out why.

one of the other stages was the preassembler, and I had defined the following struct (on a different header file) and it was fine:

```
typedef struct macro{
    char* name;
    char* code;
} macro;
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Strongly suggest preprocessor guards against multiple inclusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a pointer to a `struct` type without a declaration for the struct type. But `label` isn't a `struct` type, and you use it before `label` is (finished being) declared.

```c
label* next;
```

should be

```
struct label* next;
```

Comment: That seemed to solve it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct label{
    char name[MAX_LABEL_LENGTH]; 
    int line; /*the line the table was defined*/ 
    int type;
    int counterType;
    label* next;   /* <--- the error should appear here */
} label;
/* the type label is defined just after the semicolon above, not inside the struct */
```

The undefined type `label` cannot appear inside the structure, until it is known as a type by the compiler (something that happens after the `typedef` declaration)

use the full type definition inside the struct, as in:

```
typedef struct label{
    char name[MAX_LABEL_LENGTH]; 
    int line; /*the line the table was defined*/ 
    int type;
    int counterType;
    struct label* next;
} label;
```

that uses an incomplete type definition `struct label` to declare the pointer, or do it in two steps, as in:

```
typedef struct label label; /* label is an incomplete type, but the compiler knows here it is a type */

struct label{
    char name[MAX_LABEL_LENGTH]; 
    int line; /*the line the table was defined*/ 
    int type;
    int counterType;
    label* next;  /* now label is known to the compiler */
};
```

(the pointer declaration in the `struct` definition allows you to use a type name that has not yet been completed, but never an identifier that is unkown to the compiler)

When you define a new type (by means of `typedef`) the compiler adds it to the types symbol table, and so, you can use them in the place where a type identifier (or a type) can be used.  But not doing that implies that the compiler cannot allow it to appear in the syntax places reserved for type definitions, and this makes the error to appear.